# How can I display bytearray array on screen?

Tags: python, micropython, raspberry-pi-pico, thonny

I am using a ST7789 coded oled screen and raspberry pi pico board for a project. After a long struggle, I understood some things. But I couldn't find how to print the bytearray array to the screen. I'm having a hard time because the library is different. Can you help me ?

I learned to display normal texts on the screen and to set fonts. But I don't know how to display bytearray

Comment: If you know how to display "normal texts", then can't you just transform the bytearray to a string with `str()` or `repr()`?

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: I am using st7789.py for library.

Comment: I did , I used one bytearray to do that unfortunately it did not show it

Comment: Please click [edit] and give a decent example of what you actually want to do and the code for the closest thing you have achieved so far. What's in the byte array and how do you expect it to look? Thank you.